# XSD single element without text

Tags: xml, enums, xsd

I'm new in XSD and need to define scheme requiring presence of single element without text (like first `<value>`) in sequence.

```
<enum type="state">
    <value></value>
    <value>state_update</value>
    <value>normal</value>
    <value>defective</value>
    <value>alarm</value>
    <value>unknown</value>
</enum>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSD all sibling elements with the same name must have the same type, so you can't define a different type (i.e. different validation rules) for the first value child.

The only way you can do this is with XSD 1.1 assertions; you could state in the definition of the enum element for example that

```
<assert test="value[1] = ''/>
```

or

```
<assert test="count(value[.='']) = 1"/>
```

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Xerces, Saxon, and Altova.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using XSD 1.0 and "notext" element must be not first but exactly one among others which must contain text. Is any way to such condition?